# MVC urlHelper.RouteUrl to provide the full path on the server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I'm currently doing something in OrchardCMS we're using URLRewrite so that if a user comes to the site from site.com or from site.com/orchard, they get the site.com/orchard page.

One of the problems is that it's throwing the urls in the menu because it's using urlHelper.RouteUrl which uses the wrong context and then produces a url like site.com/page1 rather than site.com/orchard/page1. Is there either a way to tell urlHelper.RouteUrl to start from a different page than the current one, or to get the function to return the full path?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the Orchard Rewrite module where you can define redirect rules like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^orchard [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /orchard/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: the problem is that we're redirecting another site, so really has to be done at IIS level.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up your application under **site.com/orchard** virtual directory and then use UrlRewrite in IIS to do appropriate 301 redirect **when user enters site.com**. This is a much cleaner approach.

HTH